# Node.js Express SQLite3: Can't Send HTML input data to SQLite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, handlebars.js

Basically, I'm trying to add an ArtistId and Name using an HTML input into my SQLite3 database. Every time I press the submit button, I receive a '404 - Not Found' page instead of the '/success' page that I set up in my view folder, and my database is not being updated. I have run a simple test to make sure that I'm connected to the database which is successful - it is commented out in the code. For this, I am using Express, Handlebars, and SQLite3. Please help me understand how to do this properly. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="/form" method="POST">
<div>
<label for="ArtistId">Artist Id: </label>
<input type="text" name="artistId">
</div>
<div>
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

### Express

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const db = new 
sqlite3.Database('./Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKs(2).sqlite');

// const query = `SELECT * FROM Artist LIMIT 5`;
// db.each(query, (err, row) => {
//   if (err) throw err;
//   console.log(row);
// });
//
// db.close();


router.get('/form', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('form');
});

app.post('/form', (req, res, next) => {
db.run(
`INSERT INTO Artist(ArtistId, Name) VALUES(${req.body.artistId}, 
${req.body.name})`,
(err, row) => {
if (err) throw err;
res.redirect(303, '/success');
}
);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where is the code for your submit button?

Comment: @JonathanRys <form action="/form" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="ArtistId">Artist Id: </label>
        <input type="text" name="artistId">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

Comment: @JonathanRys I didn't mean to submit that last comment in that format, but I guess I'll just leave it since it's not too confusing